# Adding total of array in php?

Tags: php, html, sql

I have a database and PHP file which outputs a module catogaries by the year the module was taken in. accompanying this is how much the module is worth.. eg Computer Science 10. The output on the screen needs to have the **TOTAL** of the points within that **YEAR**

So it looks like this:
**2001/02**
cs 10
bi 10
chem 10
total 30

This is all fine and works APART from if there is more years like this:
2001/02 0 points
2002/03 120 points
2003/04 120 points

But there is points in `2001/02` but the code seems to overwrite this before outputting it.

Here is the PHP code:

```
$points = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    if ($year != $row["ayr"]) {
        echo "<tr><th colspan='3'><b>" . $row["ayr"] . "</b></th></tr>";
        $year = $row["ayr"];
        echo "<td align='right'><b> Total Module Points: ".array_sum($points)."<td></b>";
        $points = array();
    }

    if ($year = $row["ayr"]) {
        array_push($points, $row["credits"]);
    }

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row["mid"] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row["mtitle"] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row["credits"] . "</td>";

    echo "<tr>";

    if ($year != $row["ayr"]) {
        echo "<td align='right'> Total Module Points: ".array_sum($points)."<td>";
    }
}
```

So the code gets the student number, output each module by year and then adds up the module points and gives a total but I cannot get the first table to work

regards

Comment: Indenting correctly will help you debug your code better.

Comment: Please expand "cannot work".

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this causes your problem?

```
if ($year = $row["ayr"]) {
    array_push($points, $row["credits"]);
}
```

Basically, $year will always be equal to $row["ayr"], is this a desired behavior?

The 'equal' comparison operator is '==' as stated before.